# error No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: java, spring, jpa, gwt, multiple-databases

MySQL, postgresql
I want to put the same data in the same name table.

- Both databases have the same table.

---

**error**

```
WARN  2017-07-04 14:53:03 o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tempMasterServiceImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManagerFactoryBean,entityManagerFactoryBean2
INFO  2017-07-04 14:53:03 o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
INFO  2017-07-04 14:53:03 o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
ERROR 2017-07-04 14:53:03 o.s.t.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@7af44dd0] to prepare test instance [jp.co.ui2.dev.server.c_one.tempServiceTest@26d8c9da]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) ~[spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) ~[spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'courseMasterServiceImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManagerFactoryBean,entityManagerFactoryBean2
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:357) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128) ~[spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: entityManagerFactoryBean,entityManagerFactoryBean2
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:546) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:685) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 39 common frames omitted
```

---

**test.properties**

```
//mysql
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/testdb

jdbc.username=test
jdbc.password=test

//postgresql
jdbc.driverClassName2=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url2=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres

jdbc.username2=postgres
jdbc.password2=postgres
```

---

**TestConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@Import({ testServerConfig.class })
public class TestConfig
{

@Bean
public PropertiesFactoryBean prop() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean f = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    f.setLocations(new Resource[] {
            new FileSystemResource("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config.properties"),
            new ClassPathResource("test.properties", getClass())
    });
    return f;
}
```

}

---

**tempServiceTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class, loader =AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class ShopInfoServiceTest extends AbstractServiceTest
{

@Autowired
private tempMasterService tempService;

@Test
public void testCustomCode()
{
    // insert
    doInTransaction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            tempMaster info = createTemp( );
            tempService.insertTempMaster(info);

        }
    });

}

private tempMaster createTemp () {

    tempMaster xxx = new tempMaster ();

    xxx.setTempId(1);
    xxx.setTempName("chaco1234");
    xxx.setDescription("tttttt2232");
    xxx.setUserId("admin");
    return xxx;
}
```

}

---

**testServerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.co.test.dev" }, excludeFilters = {
    @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Controller.class),
    @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class) })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching
@ImportResource("classpath:job-context.xml")
public class testServerConfig
{
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext ctx;

@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

@Value("#{prop['jdbc.driverClassName'] ?: ''}")
private String jdbcDriverClassName;


@Value("#{prop['jdbc.url'] ?: ''}")
private String jdbcUrl;

@Value("#{prop['jdbc.username'] ?: ''}")
private String jdbcUsername;

@Value("#{prop['jdbc.password'] ?: ''}")
private String jdbcPassword;


@Value("#{prop['jdbc.driverClassName2'] ?: ''}")
private String jdbcDriverClassName2;

@Value("#{prop['jdbc.url2'] ?: ''}")
private String jdbcUrl2;

@Value("#{prop['jdbc.username2'] ?: ''}")
private String jdbcUsername2;

@Value("#{prop['jdbc.password2'] ?: ''}")
private String jdbcPassword2;

@Value("#{prop['hibernate.dialect2'] ?: ''}")
private String hibernateDialect2;


@Value("#{prop['jdbc.initialSize'] ?: '0'}")
private int jdbcInitialSize;

@Value("#{prop['jdbc.maxActive'] ?: '50'}")
private int jdbcMaxActive;

@Value("#{prop['jdbc.maxIdle'] ?: '5'}")
private int jdbcMaxIdle;

@Value("#{prop['jdbc.maxWait'] ?: '5000'}")
private int jdbcMaxWait;

@Value("#{prop['jdbc.minIdle'] ?: '0'}")
private int jdbcMinIdle;

@Value("#{prop['jdbc.testWhileIdle'] ?: 'false'}")
private boolean jdbcTestWhileIdle;

@Value("#{prop['jdbc.testOnBorrow'] ?: 'false'}")
private boolean jdbcTestOnBorrow;

@Value("#{prop['jdbc.validationQuery'] ?: ''}")
private String jdbcValidationQuery;

@Value("#{prop['hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto'] ?: 'update'}")
private String hibernateDDLAuto;

@Value("#{prop['hibernate.dialect'] ?: ''}")
private String hibernateDialect;

@Value("#{prop['hibernate.search.indexBase'] ?: ''}")
private String searchIndexBase;

@Value("#{prop['hibernate.packages.to.scan'] ?: ''}")
private String packagesToScan;

protected String getRealPath(String path)
{
    if ((ctx != null) && (ctx instanceof WebApplicationContext)
            && (((WebApplicationContext) ctx).getServletContext() != null)) return ((WebApplicationContext) ctx)
            .getServletContext().getRealPath(path);
    else return "src/main/webapp/" + path;
}

@Bean
public PropertiesFactoryBean prop()
{
    String path = getRealPath("/WEB-INF/config.properties");
    PropertiesFactoryBean f = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    f.setLocation(new FileSystemResource(path));
    return f;
}

@Bean(name="dataSource")
public DataSource dataSource()
{
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(jdbcDriverClassName);
    ds.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
    ds.setUsername(jdbcUsername);
    ds.setPassword(jdbcPassword);
    ds.setInitialSize(jdbcInitialSize);
    ds.setMaxActive(jdbcMaxActive);
    ds.setMaxIdle(jdbcMaxIdle);
    ds.setMaxWait(jdbcMaxWait);
    ds.setMinIdle(jdbcMinIdle);
    ds.setTestWhileIdle(jdbcTestWhileIdle);
    ds.setValidationQuery(jdbcValidationQuery);
    return ds;
}

@Bean(name="dataSource2")
public DataSource dataSource2()
{
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(jdbcDriverClassName2);
    ds.setUrl(jdbcUrl2);
    ds.setUsername(jdbcUsername2);
    ds.setPassword(jdbcPassword2);
    ds.setInitialSize(jdbcInitialSize);
    ds.setMaxActive(jdbcMaxActive);
    ds.setMaxIdle(jdbcMaxIdle);
    ds.setMaxWait(jdbcMaxWait);
    ds.setMinIdle(jdbcMinIdle);
    ds.setTestWhileIdle(jdbcTestWhileIdle);
    ds.setValidationQuery(jdbcValidationQuery);
    return ds;
}

@Bean(name="entityManagerFactoryBean")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean()
{
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
    if (packagesToScan != null) {
        String[] pts = packagesToScan.split(",");
        emf.setPackagesToScan(pts);
    }
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("hibernate.archive.autodetection", "class");
    p.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
    p.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
    p.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    p.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hibernateDDLAuto);
    //naming-strategy
    p.setProperty("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
    emf.setJpaProperties(p);
    return emf;
}
@Bean(name="entityManagerFactoryBean2")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean2()
{
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
    if (packagesToScan != null) {
        String[] pts = packagesToScan.split(",");
        emf.setPackagesToScan(pts);
    }
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("hibernate.archive.autodetection", "class");
    p.setProperty("hibernate.dialect2", hibernateDialect2);
    p.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
    p.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    p.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hibernateDDLAuto);
    //naming-strategy
    p.setProperty("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
    emf.setJpaProperties(p);
    return emf;
}


@Bean(name="transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
{
    JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
    tm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
    return tm;
}
@Bean(name="transactionManager2")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager2()
{
    JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
    tm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean2().getObject());
    return tm;
}

@Bean
public EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager()
{
    EhCacheCacheManager cm = new EhCacheCacheManager();
    cm.setCacheManager(ehcache().getObject());
    return cm;
}

@Bean
public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehcache()
{
    EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factory = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setConfigLocation(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:ehcache.xml"));
    return factory;
}

@Bean(name = "configSftpSessionfactoryId")
public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftp = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    sftp.setHost(sftpHost);
    sftp.setPort(sftpPort);
    sftp.setUser(sftpUser);
    sftp.setPassword(sftpPassword);
    if (sftpPrivateKey != null && !"".equals(sftpPrivateKey)) {
        sftp.setPrivateKey(resourceLoader.getResource(sftpPrivateKey));
        sftp.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(sftpPrivateKeyPassphrase);
    }
    sftp.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return sftp;
}
```

}

---

**tempMasterServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@Transactional
@SwabAdminAuthCheck
public class tempMasterImpl implements tempMasterService{
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public void insertTempMaster(tempMaster obj) throws SwabException {

    Query keyq = em.createQuery("select tempId from tempMaster where userId = :userId");

    keyq.setParameter("userId", obj.getUserId());

    Integer tmepId = null;
    try{
        tempId = (Integer)keyq.getSingleResult();
        obj.setTempId( tempId );
    } catch (NoResultException  nre){

    }

    tempMaster searchData = em.find(tempMaster.class, obj);

    if (searchData == null) {
        logger.debug("insert");
        em.persist(obj);
    } else {
        logger.debug("update");
        em.merge(obj);
    }
}
```

}

---

Comment: I want to know the problem.

Comment: Bean definition of "courseMasterServiceImpl"?

Comment: @Afridi
That's the part I made the wrong mistake.Think of it as tempServiceImpl.

Comment: Where you autowire `entityManagerFactoryBean`? Use `@Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryBean")` to inject correct bean

Comment: @Jay Smith What do you mean?

Comment: Just change this line @Bean(name="entityManagerFactoryBean2") with @Bean(name= {"entityManagerFactoryBean2", "entityManagerFactory"}) and check it again

Comment: @Afridi

Bean (name = "entityManagerFactoryBean2")   ---->
Bean(name = { "entityManagerFactoryBean2", "entityManagerFactory"})

This is the same problem.

Comment: Try annotating your `entityManagerFactoryBean()` method with `@Primary`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Use [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setPersistenceUnitName-java.lang.String-) method to distinguish `entityManagerFactoryBean` and `entityManagerFactoryBean2`. Set different name for both `EntityManagerFactoryBean`. To inject Entitymanager use `@PersistenceContext(unitName="unitName") private EntityManager em;`

Comment: @AbdullahKhan This is the same problem.

Comment: @JaySmith PersistenceContext (unitName = "entityManagerFactoryBean") And PersistenceContext (unitName = "entityManagerFactoryBean2") private EntityManager em2; ?

Comment: Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: @Cha According to the Exception log, issue is in definition of "courseMasterServiceImpl" bean. But the code you uploaded don't have such bean. So it looks like you didn't provided complete source code.

Comment: @Afridi I uploaded a related file under bean

Answer (score 0):

Will this source help?

**datasourse-config.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource2"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName2}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url2}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username2}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password2}" />
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
</bean> 
<bean id="transactionManager2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactoryBean2" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean2"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect2}</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

---

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

**spring-config.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
      <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
      <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

    <!-- 非同期処理タスクExecutor -->
    <bean id="asyncTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />

    <!-- バリデーションプロセッサ -->
    <bean id="validatingItemProcessor" class="org.springframework.batch.item.validator.ValidatingItemProcessor">
      <property name="validator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.validator.SpringValidator">
          <property name="validator">
            <!-- Hibernate バリデータ -->
            <bean name="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
          </property>
        </bean>
       </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- property config file -->
    <bean id="propertyFilebean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="location" value="config.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dummyTasklet" class="jp.co.ui2.sms.batch.tasklet.DummyTasklet">
      <property name="batchStatus">
        <value type="org.springframework.batch.core.BatchStatus">FAILED</value>
      </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```